# STL/Boost Replacement for WideCharToMultiByte-function

Tags: c++, boost

In the following code (snippet) `WideCharToMultiByte` is a Windows specific function.

Is there a suitable replacement for the function using **STL** or **Boost**?

```
//in function parameters: (..., WCHAR* szNameOfDll, ...)

char szSourceTemp[MAX_PATH + 1] = {0};

WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,0,szNameOfDLL,-1, szSourceTemp,MAX_PATH,NULL,NULL);
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: [`std::wcstombs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcstombs)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
std::wctomb/std::wcstombs
std::mbtowc/std::mbstowcs
```

or

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <iostream>

std::string  utf8_string  = to_utf<char>(latin1_string,"Latin1");
std::wstring wide_string  = to_utf<wchar_t>(latin1_string,"Latin1");
std::string  latin1_string= from_utf(wide_string,"Latin1");
std::string  utf8_string2 = utf_to_utf<char>(wide_string);
```